# How pandas determine the data type of field when loading csv or json to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to find an answer on how pandas determine schema of a field when we are loading csv or json to a data frame

Suppose I am loading a csv file

1. What will happen if the field contains all the values as string and one float value
2. What will happen if the field contains all the values as integer and one NULL value

Any lead will be a great help. Thanks in advance :)